# What makes one wizard more powerful than another?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Harry Potter universe, a recurring theme is that some wizards are more powerful than others. For instance, Voldemort is considered to be an immensely powerful wizard, and so is Dumbledore.

However, I struggle to see how exactly this power could be quantified, or what exactly it would *mean* for a wizard to be more powerful than another.

Do any of the books mention how power is quantified? Or how a wizard becomes more powerful?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean that a Wizard is more powerful than another?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186277/what-does-it-mean-that-a-wizard-is-more-powerful-than-another) see also [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/91228/98028), among others. There's also [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/83924/98028) and its duplicate.

Comment: @Jenayah Strange that I couldn't find this via the search function

Comment: Tip: HP is one mess of a tag, if you're going to search stuff, use the `title:` operator. Filters a lot of fluff out. For instance, [`harry-potter title:powerful`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bharry-potter%5D+title%3Apowerful)

Comment: Jenayah, someone must have cast a mess making charm on it

Comment: The nominal duplicate asks specifically about duelling, and in particular Avada Kedavra.  [This one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/80471/5930) is more to the point.